# 404 only on images Laravel on Apache2 Server in Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I have a Laravel project deployed on amazon ec2 instance where all default settings are set.
The routes are working correctly, even the css and javascript files are loading.

But all the images are all giving 404.

For example: `<img id="logo" alt="Business" src="{{asset('/icons/logo.jpg')}}"></a>` gets resulted into `server.com/icons/logo.jpg` so the route is getting converted all right.

On my vagrant machine, it's showing correctly.

But not displaying the image.
What could be the problem area, Server instance, Laravel or Apache or .htaccess settings ?

Comment: Even though the images work, does the double slash persist on your local version?

Comment: Sorry, my bad the double slash was entered by mistake. It's not in original url.

Comment: Did you inspect web server's error log? It should give you the exact path requested.

Comment: Check you directory permission for images folder and add your .htaccess body.

Comment: hello, I have a similar problem, did you fix it ?